# Why does a declared prototype's function type not need to match the actual function's type?

Tags: c, prototype

I have a file1 that  uses the function `function_1`. In a file2 that I compile with file1, I defined the function as `int function_1(char a)`. In my file1, I have the prototype line `void function_1(char a)`. When I compile and test, everything works fine and I don't have any warnings. Why is this ok? Why even ask for the prototype function type if it works either way?

edit: I appreciate the warnings, but only melpomene has even made an attempt to answer the question that was asked, although I am not satisfied with the answer. If the linker doesn't check types, why should it even be part of the declaration at all?

Comment: You're supposed to put the function prototype in a `.h` file, and `#include` that `.h` file in both files. That way, the compiler can check the function prototype against the function definition, and give you a warning when they're different. You can sometimes get away with lying to the compiler (as in your example), but it does you no good to do that. Instead, you should work with the compiler to get your code right.

Comment: You lied to your compiler.  Be sure that the compiler will get its own back sooner or later.  Lying to a compiler is a dangerous habit to get into.

Comment: I am working on an assignment that requires that we do not use .h files, and there is no guarantee that we know what function type the grader will use when they compile their file containing the function with our file1. Could you please elaborate on why the compiler doesn't see anything wrong with it and why my code executes just fine? Is it because the prototype is not referenced unless there is a problem in the code?

Comment: It's because the compiler does all checks for the single file it's been given, and the compilation result just contains a reference to the name `function_1`. The linker doesn't check any types, it just connects names. `function_1` doesn't even have to be a function in the other file (but you'll probably get a runtime crash).

Comment: *"there is no guarantee that we know what function type the grader will use when they compile their file"*. Part of the assignment is to make sure that you get that information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The question seems to me to be "why doesn't the compiler *help me not make a mistake*." This seems like an entirely reasonable question, and phrasing it as "lying" to the compiler seems disingenuous--humans make mistakes.

Comment: OP, note that the first comment also partly answers the question: the compiler **does** do type-checking against prototypes, but *only if the prototype is actually visible in the compilation unit*. This is part of the cost of the header-file scheme for making incremental/parallel builds possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the compiler does all checks for the single file it's been given, and the compilation result just contains a reference to the name `function_1`. The linker doesn't check any types, it just connects names.

C uses types for two purposes:

1. For consistency checks (to prevent (some) obvious mistakes by the programmer)
2. For code generation (the types tell the compiler how much memory to reserve for variables, what code to generate to access them, etc.)

All of this is done one compilation unit at a time. (A compilation unit is basically a .c file and all the headers it includes.)

You can declare the same name with different types in different compilation units. (Because the compiler only considers one unit at a time, it won't catch this.)

But that means you have two pieces of code with different ideas about what kind of entity the program is dealing with. This can lead to fun and exciting bugs at runtime. The exact details depend on your platform/ABI.

For example, on x86 a `float` and an `int` have the same size (4 bytes). You can define a function

```
float foo(void) { return 42.0f; }
```

in file A and declare it as

```
int foo(void);
```

in file B. You might expect the resulting program to mostly work, except it would reinterpret the bit pattern for `42.0f` as an integer. But that's not what happens: The calling convention specifies that an `int` is returned in the `%eax` register whereas a `float` uses the `%st0` floating-point register. The likely result is that A will put `42.0f` in `%st0` but B will take whatever happens to be in `%eax` as the return value of `foo`.

(This can go wrong in more interesting ways: You could have e.g. `float bar[] = { ... };` in one file and `void bar(void);` in the other. This will probably result in the second file interpreting the contents of the floating-point array as machine code (to be executed when calling `bar()`).)

This is why the compiler needs to know the types of the parameters and return value: It's so it can generate the right code for a function call (putting arguments where the function expects them, and retrieving the return value from where the function put it).

But unfortunately it doesn't cross-check declarations in multiple files, relying on the programmer to get it right. That's why it is best practice to declare your "exported" (or "public") functions (i.e. those don't marked as `static`) in a header file that is included both by the file that defines the functions and by users of those functions. This way you don't need to manually declare functions you want to call, and if you do it anyway, any type mismatches will be caught as an invalid/incompatible redeclaration.